# Trying to use ng-multiselect inside ngfor. unable get selected data properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, multi-select

I have a json where there will be a dynamic data. So, i am looping through ngfor and inside ngfor i need a dropdown with search feature and multi select. so am using ng-multiselect-dropdown.

here is my stackblitz tried code --> [click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-dropdown-zdterk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
     <div class="row" *ngFor="let abc of dropdownList1; let i = index">
{{abc.Meteritem_text}}  <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'" [data]="abc.services" [(ngModel)]="abc.selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings"    name='countrySelect'> </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
 </div>
```

If i select any value in dropdown, it's selecting all checkboxes. please suggest where am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dropdownSettings for the ng-multiselect dropdown was wrong. The idField: "item_id" should be idField: "id" for ngFor loop's ng-multiselect dropdown..

I have edited your stackblitz code to make it work. Please verify:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multiselect-dropdown-3gdrew?file=app/app.component.ts